# Migration from vanilla JS to React: architecture design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, architecture

We are going to migrate this 3D editor from Vanilla JS to React:

https://threejs.org/editor/

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/editor

We are going to plan how to do so. Among the initial plan steps would be architecture design. I was wondering if there is any reference on how to design the React architecture for such a project. We are just trying to make sure we won't miss anything. Thanks.

Comment: State management for such thing can quickly become hell. You should model the state and dependencies/change flows carefully. The rest should be easy. If you are new to React check out some of the component libraries like MUI for inspiration.

Comment: @MartinChaov Thanks. Is there any ReactJS library or tool to make the state management more convenient?

Comment: I am suggesting not to go down the "ReactXXX tool" road. Design the state, implement it with what's best for your use-case, then hook it with your view. React is a library for managing views and has some rudimentary state management, don't use it as a foundation of your application.

Comment: @MartinChaov Thanks. I'm going to share with my teammates.

Answer (score 0):

We found a productive tool for this migration: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber

It has many advantages ✅  We will investigate more.

Also, it has this helper repo: https://github.com/pmndrs/drei

Also, there is 3D editor implemented by it: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-editor